# How can i write all console output to a file?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to write all console output to file?
When researching i only find ways to create loggers, but that wouldn't give me the logs generated by packages i use. I want to retrieve ALL logs.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please provide more details what exactly you want to accomplish. Do you want to see logs when debugging your development app, is it for a production app in the user hand to track user actions, is it for testing, ...

Comment: i want to enable our customer to send us the logs after testing

Comment: Have a look at [Apple's recommendations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging/generating_log_messages_from_your_code)

Answer (score 0):

There are methods in Swift Standard Library:

```
func print<Target>(_ items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default, to output: inout Target) where Target : TextOutputStream
```

You can create an object that implements TextOutputStream that will save a message to a file of your choice. This is very useful if you already have existing prints in the codebase. You can then just add the additional parameter to them. Remember that those prints will then stop logging to the standard output (console).

[Documentation for print](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1641736-print)

Example:

```
final class LogDestination: TextOutputStream {
  private let path: String
  init() {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    path = paths.first! + "/log"
  }

  func write(_ string: String) {
    if let data = string.data(using: .utf8), let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: path) {
      defer {
        fileHandle.closeFile()
      }
      fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
      fileHandle.write(data)
    }
  }
}
```

And then

```
// I would probably use Singleton for this
var dest = LogDestination()
print("My test message", to: &dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

A "console" (terminal) is usually attached to *stderr* or *stderr* file descriptors. The console views the text written by programs to these file descriptors.

On iOS, the Swift `print` function writes to *stdout*, unless another output stream has been specified.

The `NSLog` function writes to *stderr* in addition to the [Unified Logging system](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/logging).

`os_log` writes to the Unified Logging system and is also tied to stderr.

Now, one can collect messages send via os_log using *sysdiagnose* tool. Users need to follow a certain procedure to get to the log archive and may send it via mail to you, which isn't the most convenient thing to do, honestly. [Here is more info how a user can find any of the various archives containing logs](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/profiles-and-logs/). These messages also contain a wealth of information - but no messages sent to stdout or stderr (as far as I know).

In order to capture messages sent to *stderr* or *stdout* - which also contain messages sent to `os_log` you may *redirect* or duplicate the file streams and let them target a file on the device which you specify in our code.

Below is an example how to capture (should we say "subscribe") to stderr and stdout and write the content to a file:

```
import Darwin
import os.log

extension OSLog {
    private static var subsystem = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
    static let test = OSLog(subsystem: subsystem, category: "Test")
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

        if true /*isatty(STDERR_FILENO) != 1*/ { // if no terminal is attached to stderr
            let documentsUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            let logfileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("out.log")
            logfileUrl.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { path in
                guard let path = path else {
                    return
                }
                print("redirect stderr and stderr to: \(String(cString: path))")
                let file = fopen(path, "a")
                assert(file != nil, String(cString: strerror(errno)))
                let fd = fileno(file)
                assert(fd >= 0, String(cString: strerror(errno)))
                let result1 = dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO)
                assert(result1 >= 0, String(cString: strerror(errno)))
                let result2 = dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO)
                assert(result2 >= 0, String(cString: strerror(errno)))

                os_log("***** os_log: Test", log: OSLog.test, type: .debug)
                print("***** print:Test")
                NSLog("***** NSLog: Test")
            }
        }
        os_log("os_log: Test", log: OSLog.test, type: .debug)
        print("print: Test")
        NSLog("NSLog: Test")
        return true
    }
}
```

This implementation uses a few posix functions - which I prefer when you write lower level file related code. You may find Foundation more convenient.

The code above opens a log file (and creates it if it does not exist) and appends all messages to it written from any code - that is, your own code and any system or third party library - which eventually writes to stderr or stdout (which also includes os_log).